# Send email alert when receiving mail on a different address

Tags: linux, email, gmail

I currently have 3 email addresses for various things (university, work, personal - all gmail addresses) - I'm trying to stay notified of new emails in all three, but the widely-used methods aren't right for me. As I googled, these options seem to be;

1. Forward all mail to one address (personal makes sense)
2. Use a PC / mobile application to monitor all 3 - or even use a mail client exclusively, rather than browser-based clients

The first one I don't like, simply because work/school email doesn't belong in my personal mailbox ánd there's the risk I accidentally reply to an email from said personal address. I realise I can add aliases to be able to send from my other 2 addresses, but since my work email has a load of aliasses itself, that's going to get really messy. And again, the emails don't belong there in the first place.

Now the second one sounds obvious, but I don't like it. I'm not always at my desktop or laptop, and email alerters for mobile suck up a surprising amount of power, draining the battery.

Since I'm already monitoring my personal mail on my smartphone, the ideal solution for me would be to receive an email alert on my personal mail, so I know to login to the other mail. This could be done in several ways

1. Ideally, a built-in gmail function. I looked at gmail's filters but there's no option to send a mail when receiving a mail.
2. An application that monitors the other addresses (pretty sure gmail supports both pop and imap), sends a mail to the main address, and can be run on linux. That way I can just run it on a VPS or an already running dedicated server.

Well, that's a lot of text for a simple question...

**tldr;**
Send email to an email-address, when receiving mail on another email-address. How I do dat?

Comment: This request makes no sense to me.  If you are already monitoring a mailbox - why not monitor the original one?

Comment: @sds because then I'd be monitoring 3 mailboxes rather than 1